# SpriteKit SKTexture Crash

Tags: sprite-kit, cifilter, skspritenode

Not sure why this doesnt work.

It crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it tries to create the ship node.

```
SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[filter setValue:@0.6 forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];

SKTexture *texDone;

if (filter) {
    texDone = [tex textureByApplyingCIFilter:filter];
}

if (texDone) {
    SKSpriteNode *ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texDone];
    [self addChild:ship];
    ship.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
}
```

same crash as creating the ship.

I have used this SKEffect, but it is a lot more code ? For same filter. The following works.

```
SKSpriteNode *spriteToFilter = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[filter setValue:@1.0 forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];

SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
effectNode.filter = filter;
effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

[effectNode addChild:spriteToFilter];
[self addChild:effectNode];
effectNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a bug in `SKTexture` as discussed in the dev forums [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/894095). Following the lldb trace, I would guess it's a memory management problem with how it allocates the image data buffers when using filters. If you really want to avoid using `SKEffectNode`, this code should get you around it by handling the filters directly and avoiding the reliance on `SKTexture`.

```
UIImage *ship = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
CIImage *shipImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:ship];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, shipImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6], nil];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *out = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cg = [context createCGImage:out fromRect:[out extent]];
SKTexture *texDone = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:cg];
```

Tested and working here, but probably easier to just use the `SKEffectNode` code you posted. Not sure which is more efficient, you'll have to play around with them.

```
// adding the texture to a sprite with above filter works
SKSpriteNode *spriteToFilter = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texDone];
[self addChild:spriteToFilter];
spriteToFilter.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
```

Comment: Yeah has to be a bug, if I want a SKSpriteNode then I cannot have one thats an image thats been filtered... I'm stuck with an SKEffect Node.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with particles in Sprite Kit -- it seemed to be because the source texture was in a Texture Atlas folder, and it didn't have the corresponding @2x image. Try moving the texture out of the texture atlas and/or adding an @2x version of the image.